# Trying to symmetrize bones, not working

Tags: armature, bones

When I select half of the bones on one side of my armature right click and hit symmetrize, the bones do not appear. I may be doing something wrong, or just being a noob and missing something simple. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure each bone name to be mirrored ends with ".L" which means LEFT (e.g.: hand.L) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to center the cursor.
Hopefully that will help.